# eclipse console always maximizes

Tags: eclipse, console, editor

I want eclipse console when clicked to open at the bottom ( south ). Instead it always opens maximized. I want to see the package explorer/editor and console in one view when an error occurs. But when the console has been minimized and I click on it, the console opens taking up the whole screen.

What do i need to do for it to open to a smaller area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double click on it (on the name) and it will take its place with the other views at the buttom.
If it minimized but was at a higher level than the others:
just grab it(from the name) and move to other views' level.

Comment: Wow - I remember this from the first time I used eclipse.  Somehow I managed to maximize everything and couldn't undo it.  It was seriously driving me crazy.  Several years later and it works great once you figure it out.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. I have been using Ctrl-M alone and for some reason it seems ok. I must have unknowingly double clicked as Haarut sais above.